# At most one record can return by sub query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to arrive Remaining Stock from products. I have 3 Tables Product, ReceivedProducts, Sold.

**Product Table** Contain ProducuId,ProductName,InitialQuantity,Cost

**ReceivedProduct Table** contain ProductId & ReceivedQuantity

**Sold Table** contain ProductId & SoldQuantity

Now i need to get the Remaining Quantity of each products that is

((**InitialStock**+ **ReceievedStock**) - **SoldStock**)

I tried two different query's but getting error

```
SELECT ProductId, InitialStock, 
(SELECT ReceivedQty FROM ReceivedProducts WHERE Product=ProductStock.ProductId) AS ReceivedStock 
FROM ProductStock;  //At most one record can return by sub query

SELECT ProductId, 
InitialStock+SUM(ReceivedQty) AS TotalQty 
FROM ProductStock AS PSD INNER JOIN ReceivedProducts AS RP ON PSD.ProductId=RP.Product
GRUOP BY PSD.ProductId,InitialStock;  // Syntax error
```

Please help me to solve this i need remaining Quantity of each product !

Comment: Thank you @juergend i solved but am getting only one row because ReceivedStock contain 2 rows for same product. But in InitialStock is available for all products so I need to display all products current stock ? how to form query ?

Comment: [Detail Question](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/753965/At-most-one-record-can-return-by-sub-query-in-MS-A) Please refer this question